# Error writing a post filter for solr 5.3

Tags: solr

I have followed http://qaware.blogspot.in/2014/11/how-to-write-postfilter-for-solr-49.html for writing a post filter. Currently i have the following error stack trace. Can some one shed some light on why the class i wrote is unable to be cast to the parent class it is extending. 
`org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error Instantiating queryParser, Pathology.Parser.NLPFilterPlugin failed to instantiate org.apache.solr.search.QParserPlugin
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:820)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:659)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:727)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:447)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:438)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor$1.run(ExecutorUtil.java:210)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error Instantiating queryParser, Pathology.Parser.NLPFilterPlugin failed to instantiate org.apache.solr.search.QParserPlugin
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInstance(SolrCore.java:588)
    at org.apache.solr.core.PluginBag.createPlugin(PluginBag.java:122)
    at org.apache.solr.core.PluginBag.init(PluginBag.java:217)
    at org.apache.solr.core.PluginBag.init(PluginBag.java:206)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:764)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class Pathology.Parser.NLPFilterPlugin
    at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:3208)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:475)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:422)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInstance(SolrCore.java:567)
    ... 13 more`

Comment: How you solve your problem. I am facing same issue with solr 5.4. I am following this tutorial https://lucidworks.com/blog/2015/05/15/custom-security-filtering-solr-5/